# Creating and visualizing a Linked List

Tags: data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm still new to coding and I'm trying to learn how to create a linked list. What does this part mean? I can't seem to visualize this in my head.

```
static class Node { 
   int data; 
   Node next; 
   Node(int d){ 
      data = d; 
      next = null;} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a simple visual of a linked list. Your code represents a node class, so thats just the framework for a node. But you can think of that code representing one node, so it could represent the fourth node in this diagram. Thus, its data value would be {D} and its next value would be null.

In a linked list, the next node object it represented by the next variable. So if the node you are looking at is the second node, then your next variable will be the third node.

[image]